# android firebase only one device token can access the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Database and auth (phone linked with email),
For one to one chat App
My issue is in my App only one device can send or receive messages If I created a user from another device this user can't access the Firebase Database.
But if I logged in with this user from my device it can access the DB Only my device can access the Firebase DB

Please Help.

Comment: Can you try to enable another login method and repeat the experiment?

Comment: I'm using phone auth login method then create another user by email and password login method linked with phone user.